# Filter all sentences containing this and that word, R

Tags: r, string, filter

I have a dataset with a text column of millions of sentences. I want to filter out all the sentences that contain *either* of these words

```
immigr* 
migra*
asyl*
refug*
```

Is there a neat little function for that which I don't know of?
So far I've tried with

```
grep('immigr+', df$text)
```

But it can only take one word at the time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collapse values with or (`|`):

```
wd <- c("immigr*","migra*", "asyl*", "refug*")
grep(paste(wd, collapse = "|"), c("immigra", "other"))
1
```